# Reading textbox values in a table in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor Webassembly and on one page I have a table of images, each image has a textbox for title and description and a save button. So each row looks like this:

```
Image :: Name :: Description :: Save button
```

What I want is to click in the Save button and get the value of name and description of the current row.

I am calling an method passing in the row id. But how could I get the values of the textboxes for that particular row?

How can in textbox values in runtime, I tried to apply binding but I have many rows so cannot get textbox values easily.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component to host the row, and bind the text fields.

**RowComponent**

```
<tr>
    <td><input @bind-value=@Item.Name /></td>
    <td><input @bind-value=@Item.Description /></td>
    <td><button @onclick=@HandleClick</td>
</tr>

@Code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<ItemInfo> OnClick { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Description { get; set; }

    public class ItemInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    ItemInfo Item = new ItemInfo();

    async Task HandleClick()
    {
        await OnClick.InvokeAsync(Item);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Item = new ItemInfo
        {
            Name = Name,
            Description = Description
        };
    }
}
```

Put the rows in your parent component and catch the event with the ItemInfo included.

**ParentComponent**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            <RowComponent Name=@item.Name
                          Description=@item.Description
                          OnClick=@HandleClick />
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    async Task HandleClick(ItemInfo itemInfo)
    {
        string enteredName = itemInfo.Name;
        string enteredDescription = itemInfo.Description;
    }
}
```